# MySQL integer column with string search returns the invalid result

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me to understand the MySQL select query behavior and help me to solve this,

**How to show no results found message based on user search?**

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `dummytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mobile` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `welcome` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

[image]

**Question**: Why I am getting this result?

```
SELECT * FROM `dummytable` WHERE `mobile` = '\'\'' LIMIT 50
```

[image]

Comment: if we add WHERE `mobile` = 'okay' is also results the same. Anyone can help to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column `mobile` is declared as an integer.  When MySQL compares an integer to a string, then it converts the string to a number -- not the other way around.

How does MySQL do this?  It converts the leading numeric characters to a number.  Your condition is:

```
WHERE mobile = ''''
```

(The traditional SQL way to put a single quote in a string is to double it up.)

The single quote is not a numeric character, so the conversion results in `0`.  And hence, that is the result that you get.

Comment: how to solve this.. If people are searching okay on input box then the result become invalid. How to solve this, In this case I have to display no results found.

Comment: Test the input value outside the database. If you are coming from php, do the test there.

Answer (score 1):

Your column `mobil` is an integer column. So everything is converted to int. An empty string is converted to 0 (and any other string not starting with a number will also be converted to zero I think)

Comment: yes if we add WHERE `mobile` = 'okay' is also results the same

Answer (score 1):

After execution of this query MySQL shows you a warning message:

```
mysql> select * from foo where bar_integer='\'\''

....

10 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'okay' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL tries to convert you string value to destination type (integer), if convertion fails mysql interprites it as 0 which results to what you see.

If you turn on MySQL strict mode this query would produce an error instead of making this implicit cast.

Comment: how to solve this.. If people are searching okay on input box then the result become invalid. How to solve this, In this case I have to display no results found

Comment: You should validate user input on client side before querying mysql. It's not a mysql problem.